# Is there a way in JabRef to modify the "related Article" Tab?

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

Beginning next year, I will start my promotion. So currently I am preparing myself for this, including a way to organize the articles I have read or skimmed. So, for that, I use JabRef (on Ubuntu).

Now to my question. At the Moment, I sort all the articles and books by using the "groups". But I want to include a relatively fast and intuitive way to find the reference List of an Item. For Example, I have the Analysis I Book by Amann and Escher, and want to know what references that they used, I have in my bibliography. So, my first idea was, again, using groups. But that will surely be too much to handle. Then I find the "related article" Tab, where similar items are listed. Ideally, I would like to have just such a tab for the references. Is there anything like this?

But I am also interested in other ideas.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: ...this seems like you need help with Jabref, not (La)TeX, am I correct?

Comment: @Werner Yes, but this platform was my first idea for such a question.
If the question is out of place, feel free to delete or move it.

Answer (score 1):

The tab "Related articles" is designed to help finding external resources (i.e. new/other articles) based on a service called Mr Dlib.
While the name of this tab may sound appealing, I do not think that will help you.
Two suggestions:

- enter as keywords the BibTeX keys of the related entries.
- create a specific field to store the related BibTeX keys (look at options -> Preferences -> Custom editor tabs).

Comment: Okay, I haven't even noticed the "custom editors tabs" yet. Thanks for the hint!